# How can I use an expression for the page header height in SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL Reporting Services I would like to show the report parameters in the page header on the first page, but not the remaining pages.  I was able to do this by setting the visibility of the box containing the parameters in the page header using an expression, however, there is a white space in the header where the box was.  I would like to have the page header shrink to its contents and eliminate the white space left by the missing box.  SSRS does not allow an expression for the page header height.  How can I adjust the height of the page header on all pages but the first?

See [page header on first page](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/3631/headertall.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that it is not possible for a rectangle or header to automatically shrink in SSRS.  see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=383350